# regex for numbers only

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

I am trying to get the regex to work to remove any characters and allow only numbers and a period

I've tried:

```
[0-9]+.[^a-zA-Z]
('\\d+.\\d+')
[0-9]+.[0-9]
```

What should this pattern be?  Or do I have an error using the pattern and matcher?

```
string dist = '0.1 mi'
Pattern p = Pattern.compile('???????');
system.debug(dist);
Matcher m = p.matcher(dist);
system.debug(m.matches());
return double.valueOf(m.group(1));
```

Comment: I think you want `group(0)`...

Comment: the odd part is the m.matches() is returning false

Comment: which pattern should I use or should I use a different one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me in `Execute Anonymous`:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile('\\d+\\.\\d+').matcher('0.1 mi');
if (m.find()) system.debug(Double.valueOf(m.group())); // yields 0.1
```

Notable differences:

- I escape the `.` character (though this only makes the expression more restrictive)
- I call `find()` rather than `matches()`
- I return `group()`, which implicitly returns `group(0)`

Comment: odd, it works with find().  Do I have to call that no matter what?

Comment: Yeah I believe so.