# Invalid Decimal - Visualforce error. Am using Decimal.valueOf(string);

Tags: apex, visualforce

This is my method:

```
public static String getSumInfo() {
    String x = ChartController.getNewBusinessClosedWonJanuary(); 
    String y = ChartController.getNewBusinessClosedWonFebruary();
    Decimal x1 = Decimal.valueOf(x);
    Decimal y1 = Decimal.valueOf(y);
    Decimal num = (x1 + y1);
    if (num == null) {
        num = 0;  
    }
    return JSON.serialize(num);
}
```

When I refresh the VF page, the error: 'Invalid decimal: [89716]' appears.

Comment: Can you add a sample of the output from, or the code for `getNewBusinessClosed...`?

Comment: you probably need to get rid of the square bracket. Either inside the getNewBusiness.. methods or just remove them in the getSumInfo method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your methods `getNewBusinessClosedWonJanuary` and `getNewBusinessClosedWonFebruary` are returning excess data with the string. You'll have to filter these down to just the numbers you need for your class.

Adding a short method to filter them, and two calls to that method, would likely be a decent short-term solution, if you aren't able to modify the methods you are using in your class.

This snippet below uses [regex based off this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/134178/regex-for-numbers-only) as an example for this case. You could also use `'[^0-9]'`, but this would cause any periods to be removed, potentially modifying your decimals.

```
public static String SanitizeInput(String s) {
    Pattern numeric = Pattern.compile('(\d)?\.(\d)+');
    Matcher matcher = numeric.matcher(s);

    return matcher.find() ? matcher.group() : '';
}
```

And add a call to the newly created method in your controller. You'll need to add a check against the `x` and `y` values being `''`, since calling `Double.valueOf('');` gives an exception.

```
public static String getSumInfo() {
    String x = Controller.SanitizeInput(ChartController.getNewBusinessClosedWonJanuary()); 
    String y = Controller.SanitizeInput(ChartController.getNewBusinessClosedWonFebruary());
    Decimal x1 = Decimal.valueOf(x);
    Decimal y1 = Decimal.valueOf(y);
    Decimal num = (x1 + y1);
    if (num == null) {
        num = 0;  
    }
    return JSON.serialize(num);
}
```

Comment: If anyone has a different regex, which is more efficient, feel free to leave a comment, I am far from a regex wizard.

Comment: You need to escape `.` character or it will just match anything between digit groups. You also might want to make the first `\d` optional. So more like `(\d)?\.(\d)+`.